# x11vnc exits reverse connection immediately

Tags: vnc, remmina, x11vnc

I'm using x11vnc for reverse connection, that the help seeking persons only have to click a button (a launcher for a bash one-liner with x11vnc and a DDNS) when I ask them to do so.

I stripped down the one-liner to `x11vnc -connect vnc.domain.tld`

on Linux Mint 13 or Ubuntu 12.04 with MATE <=1.6, Xfce, KDE or Unity (`x11vnc` installed from the default repositories) everything works perfect and the last lines when establishing a connection are:

```
...
01/01/2000 00:00:00 Using tight encoding for client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
01/01/2000 00:00:00 created   xdamage object: 0x3c00036
01/01/2000 00:00:00 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 51
01/01/2000 00:00:05 client_set_net: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  5.0809
01/01/2000 00:00:09 created selwin: 0x3c00037
01/01/2000 00:00:09 called initialize_xfixes()
```

but on Debian 8, Fedora 24, Linux Mint 17.x & 18 or Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04 with MATE >=1.8, Xfce, LXDE, KDE, Cinnamon or Unity x11vnc (installed from the default repositories) exits with the last 4 terminal-lines being different: (also the waiting client exits immediately)

```
...
01/01/2000 00:00:00 Using tight encoding for client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
01/01/2000 00:00:00 client_count: 0
01/01/2000 00:00:00 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
01/01/2000 00:00:00 viewer exited.
01/01/2000 00:00:00 deleted 50 tile_row polling images.
```

so... I have no clue what and why it is not working anymore!
**what I can do to get the reverse VNC connection working again?** - or is there maybe a bug???

---

notice: the masked IP-addresses are the correct ones from the client and for sure port 5500 is forwarded to the client.

additional notice: if needed... I'm using remmina as viewer.